# How to send data (instantaneously) from one canvas to other?

Tags: html, socket.io, html5-canvas

I have developed an app using HTML5 and socket.io in which there are two types of users: writer and reader. Writer can write anything on the canvas and send it to all the readers by clicking a send button. The drawing on the canvas is displayed as an image to the readers. Now I want to improve it, so that the changes made by writer could be instantaneously reflected on a canvas on readers' page. Can anyone give me some hints please, how it could be done?

Answer (score 0):

Well, since the writing is done live, perhaps rather then recording images, you record the mouse-clicks, so as to track the actual painting being done as opposed to the image.

```
socket.send(e.mouseX+","+e.mouseY);
```

^ pseudo-code-- of course it should be more complex to support different colours etc.